# Program aborts when using strcpy on a char pointer? (Works fine on char array)

Tags: c, strcpy

I'm perplexed as to why the following doesn't work:

```
char * f = "abcdef";
strcpy(f, "abcdef");
printf("%s",f);

char s[] = "ddd";
strcpy(&s[0], "eee");
printf("%s", s);
```

In both examples strcpy received a char * yet on the first example it dies a horrible death.

Answer (score 11):

`"abcdef"` and `"ddd"` are string literals which may reside in a read-only section of your address space. `char s[] = "ddd"` ensures this literal is copied to stack - so it's modifiable.

Answer (score 6):

`char * f = "abcdef";` defines a char pointer to "abcdef" which is located in read-only area so you can't write to this place

`char s[] = "ddd";` defines a char array **on the stack** which is writable.

Answer (score 5):

In the first example, you have a pointer to a string literal.  This pointer should really be `const char *`, because any attempt to modify a string literal is undefined behaviour.  However, for legacy reasons allows you to use a `char *` to point at it.  But you still shouldn't be trying to modify it.

In the second version, you have a bog-standard array, whose contents happen to be initialised to be equivalent to your string.  This is modifiable, as it's *your* array.

Answer (score 4):

The first example is a `char *` to a character literal (a literal is `"something"`). Character literals are read-only, and attempting to write to them can result in crashes. Your first pointer should really be `const char *f = "abcdef";`, which `strcpy` won't take.

Answer (score 2):

The statement `char * f = "abcdef"` assigns a point in memory to the literal string "abcdef", however it will refuse to let you modify its contents until the memory is dynamically allocated - it's equivalent to a `const char`.
All you're doing is creating a pointer in memory and then writing over the next 6 bytes, which is illegal in C.

Answer (score 2):

String literals are considered readonly by most compilers, so the memory where they reside can be marked as readonly, resulting in a runtime error.

To make it work, do the following:

```
char * f = strdup("abcdef");
strcpy(f, "abcdef");
printf("%s",f);
free(f);
```

This creates a modifiable copy of the string in the heap memory, which needs to get freed at the end of your program of course.