# Usage of strcpy with pointers to characters

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcpy, string-literals

Why does this code crash? Is strcpy not being used properly?

[image: strcpy code]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code or error messages.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/1679849)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program aborts when using strcpy on a char pointer? (Works fine on char array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645949/program-aborts-when-using-strcpy-on-a-char-pointer-works-fine-on-char-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char \*s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

The variable `msg1` points to the memory occupied by a string literal. String literals are not modifiable. Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7. It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements > have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an 
>      array, the behavior is undefined.**

Take into account that if you want to copy a string to a character array using the standard C function `strcpy` then the array has to have enough memory to accommodate the string including its terminating zero.

You can make your code valid by substituting the pointer for a character array. For example

```
char msg1[15] = "Hello World"; 
//...
strcpy( msg1, "Hello New York" );
```